# Why MUI React Dividers don't appear in the example?

Tags: javascript, material-ui

I'm new to the Material UI and I'm building an info grid about a blog.

Here's an image of the page I'm trying to build (with the latter Divider having the lines I want):

[image: The page I'm trying to build]

I'm expecting there to be lines that would have almost struck through the text, which is the default behaviour for Divider, but there are none. Why and how to fix this?

[Click here to see the code](https://codesandbox.io/s/throbbing-dream-htzvgv?file=/src/App.js)

I've done some research beforehand and all I've found was to use "flexItem" property, however it doesn't help, because the property is used only for vertical Dividers.

P.S: I realize there may be a few things that could upset more experienced developers, such as that I'm using non-breaking space to make an empty cell, or something else. Feel free to criticize.